# No ROS_WORKSPACE set- error

Tags: ros, rosws, roscd, ros-workspace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I have been trying to create a ros workspace according to ROS tutorials.
First, I got this error

```
ERROR in config: Command requires a target workspace.
```

exactly the same  situation in this question

rosws problem fuerte

then I fixed it and I got the following output:

```
rosws set sandbox

     Add new elements:
  sandbox

Continue: (y)es, (n)o: y
Overwriting /home/turtlebot/groovy_workspace/.rosinstall

Do not forget to do ...
$ source /home/turtlebot/groovy_workspace/setup.sh
... in every open terminal.
```

But now when I try roscd command, I get this error

```
No ROS_WORKSPACE set. Please set ROS_WORKSPACE to use roscd with no arguments.
```

Any idea why?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54871/no-ros_workspace-set--error/) by [TheSkyfall](https://answers.ros.org/users/4174/theskyfall/) on ROS Answers with karma: 39 on 2013-02-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2013-02-10**:
This is a duplicate of http://answers.ros.org/question/54523/trouble-creating-sandbox-in-groovy/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a current bug in rosws, fiexed already to be released soon. In the meantime you can edit your setup.sh, and copy the line exporting ROS_WORKSPACE to the bottom of the file (copy, not move). That should fix the behavior until the fix is out. Note the setup.sh files only get updated by rosws when you run rosws regenerate.

UPDATE (thanks Boris):
Add the following line at the bottom of your ~/.bashrc

```
export ROS_WORKSPACE=/home/turtlebot/groovy_workspace
```

This line should already be at the top of the file, but the value gets removed in between. Others have to adapt the path, obviously.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-02-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TheSkyfall](https://answers.ros.org/users/4174/theskyfall/) on 2013-02-13**:
Thank you. It works.